# JUnit4 parameterized test with different Android SDK versions

Tags: android, sdk, junit4, parameterized

I'd like to test a function having a conditional statement for different Android SDK build versions with some parameters. The function looks like:

```java
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    // do something with parameter(s) and return it;
} else {
    // do something with parameter(s) and return it;
}
```

I can use `Parameterized.class` runner or JUnitParams to get it run with a set of parameters. I can also create a single test function and can change the `SDK_INT` field and call the function to test. But I was not able to combine both approaches into the same unit test class.

Is there any annotation to set the SDK for a particular test method? Or what is the best approach to test functions like the above?

Answer (score 0):

A simple yet not elegant solution is to use the [Enclosed runner](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/experimental/runners/Enclosed.html) and inner classes changing the `SDK_INT` field in a function annotated with `@BeforeClass`.